# How can I use a dialogfragments input to create cardview in realtime the MainActivity

Tags: android, android-studio, user-interface

I have created a Dialogfragment that takes the user's input for Name and number and saves them as strings.
I wanted to know how can I use those two strings to create a card view as shown in the mockup below [image: Cardview Mockup]

I want it to be able to update itself whenever a new entry is made as a new card.
How can I create it inside android studio ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User click on submit button then store these information in database and also call where the new data comes. When the new data comes then notify recycle view adapter

Comment: Thank you !

I did not knew about recycler view so this definitely guided me in the correct direction.
[This tutorial series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nw9JF55LDzE&list=PLrnPJCHvNZuBtTYUuc5Pyo4V7xZ2HNtf4) goes a long way to help me understand how this all works
really appreciate it ^-^